# Handling pointers within multiple functions in C

Tags: c, pointers, c99

I'm trying to create functions out of existing code in order to make it cleaner, and I'm having some problems:

It used to be:

```
int foo(char * s, char * t, char ** out) {
  int val = strcmp(s, t);
  if (val == 0) {
     *out = strdup(s);
     return 1;
  } else {
     *out = strdup(t);
     return 5;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Now I have:

```
int foo(char * s, char * t, char ** out) {
  someFunction(s, t, out);
  printf("%s", *out);
  return 0;
}

int someFunction(char *s, char * t, char **out) {

  int val = strcmp(s, t);
  if (val == 0) {
     *out = strdup(s);
     return 1;
  } else {
     *out = strdup(t);
     return 5;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

And I'm getting segmentation faults when I try to do the printf. Should someFunction be expecting a *out? I guess I'm still confused.

Comment: What does `someFunction` look like? Also, that can't be the code you compiled and ran, since it's missing a function name. Please paste the real code (culled for brevity, of course).

Comment: It would also be helpful to see how you are calling the (currently nameless) function.  Specifically, what are you passing in for values `s`, `t`, and `out`?  A complete, compilable example that reproduces your segfault would be ideal.

Comment: I tried to fix it as best I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is "correct" if I understand your intent.  I assume you are doing something along the lines of

```
char *s = "foo";
char *t = "bar";
char *out;
foo(s, t, out);
```

when you really want

```
char *s = "foo";
char *t = "bar";
char *out;
foo(s, t, &out);  // Note the & which passes the address of a char* to be manipulated
```

Comment: No, `foo` is your `foo`.  You are calling `foo` somewhere.  Your call to `foo` must be incorrect (as in my first example), because there is nothing wrong with the way `foo` is calling `someFunction`, or with the way that `someFunction` manipulates `*out`.

Comment: In other words, you are providing an invalid `char**` for the `out` argument of `foo`.  This ultimately causes a segfault when `someFunction` attempts a write to the invalid memory address.

Comment: So even if foo calls someFunction, ultimately out is always accessible with the right content?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "always accessible."  `out` is a pointer to a pointer.  You pass it from `foo` over to `someFunction`.  There is nothing wrong with the way you are doing this in the code you've provided.  It is correct code.  Your segfault *must* mean that your problem is in how you call `foo`.  You have not posted that code though, so it cannot be analyzed.

Comment: Wouldn't this normally trigger a compiler error since there is no explicit cast from `char*` to `char**`? I would try to compile with `gcc -Wall` and see if it fails to compile pending some incorrect casts.  Typically I would imagine gcc might warn you without the `-Wall` option, and just output a list of errors.  With the `-Wall` option though, it would stop you from incorrect pointer casts if that is indeed what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

I would convert it this way:

```
int foo(char * s, char * t, char ** out) {
    int val = strcmp(s, t); 
    *out = val ? strdup(t) : strdup(s);
    return val ? 5 : 1;
}
```

Comment: While this may be an acceptable way to refactor the function `foo` (though I would disagree as it tests `val` twice), it does not actually answer the question that was asked.

Comment: A note of thanks though, every attempt asking a question here is a) preceded by at least half an hour of head-banging-against-table and then followed by a zen-like appreciation for newfound knowledge.